# Is NEXP = co-NEXP?

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties, complexity-classes

It is known that $\mathsf{NL}=\mathsf{Co{-}NL}$ and unknown if $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{Co{-}NP}$. But what about
$$\mathsf{NEXP}=\mathsf{Co{-}NEXP}?$$
Is it known whether these two classes are equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is known that $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{coNP}$ implies $\mathsf{NEXP} = \mathsf{coNEXP}$, using a padding argument. However, both are considered unlikely.

The difference between classes like $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{NEXP}$ and the class $\mathsf{NL}$ is that the former are defined by time constraints while the latter is defined by space constraints. The Immerman–Szelepcsényi argument used to prove $\mathsf{NL}=\mathsf{coNL}$ only works for space-constrained classes.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for putting it so clearly!

Comment: Actually, an Immerman–Szelepcsényi-like argument shows the fun fact $\mathrm{NEXP/poly=coNEXP/poly}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : ​ ​ ​ In fact, that can easily be strengthened to ​ [NE/poly](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#nepoly) = coNE/poly . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Of course. I stated it for NEXP as that’s what the question is about.

Comment: @RickyDemer Could $\mathsf{NP/poly}=\mathsf{coNP/poly}$ be true? Would this have any implications?